# MagicalRecord replacement for saveNestedContexts?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, magicalrecord

I ran into some issues with data not persisting with MagicalRecord and it turned out that using `saveNestedContexts` solved the problem. However according to the documentation, that method is being deprecated. What's the new practice for storing nested objects with MagicalRecord?

Comment: I thought the new pattern was just to always use saveWithBlock: (and its variants)? I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Fogmeister Is there an example of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of these methods:

```
- (void) saveToPersistenStoreAndWait;
- (void) saveToPersistenStoreCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)completion;
- (void) saveOnlySelfAndWait;
- (void) saveOnlySelfCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)completion;
```

These methods are present in the MagicalRecord.h header file.